# psutil exception error - No such process on linux, works on windows - Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, process, psutil

I'm trying to write a program to monitor for processes in python with the psutil(the only i found that is cross platform)
i need to monitor for processes when they started, and when they have been terminated.
i made 2 lists, 1 for the current processes, and second for prev processes, and 2 loops that checks if a process in current is not in prev, then add him and print his name, and the second loop that checks if a process in prev is not in current then print his name and "terminated", the first loop works great, but the second works only on Windows, while on linux it gives me the error psutil._exceptionsNoSuchProcess

```
oldProcess = []
while 1:
    newProcess = list(psutil.process_iter())
    for process in newProcess:
        if process in oldProcess:
            continue
        else:
            print "new process: " + process.name()
            oldProcess.append(process)
    for process in oldProcess:
        if process not in newProcess:
            print "process terminated: " + process.name()
            oldProcess.remove(process)
```

Comment: the process may have been terminated when you're querying its name. You should catch the exception when querying the name.

Comment: how do i do that? and why it's works in windows?

Comment: different OSes, different race conditions... catch the exception `try/except`

Comment: it appears to work on Windows because on Windows the process name discovered in the first `for` loop is cached inside the `process` object, and is therefore always available in the second `for` loop.  I say "appears" because the same race condition applies in the first loop, it's just less likely to occur there.  On Linux the name is not cached and therefore the second loop will always be asking for the name of a process that no longer exists, which gets the exception. This is explained in the psutil documentation at http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#functions